# Magento how to quickly populate Search Terms

Tags: database, magento, phpmyadmin, synonym

I am trying to populate the Search Terms in my Magento site. How can I go about quickly populating the database with my terms and synonyms without having to manually add in all my terms. I have 100s of terms so doing it manually would take forever. I am using a CSV and would be interested in getting a myphpadmin solution or php / mysql solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query for this is as follows. The `synonym_for` field is optional. Furthermore, you must provide for which store you want to insert the terms. Go to `System > Manage stores` and hover the link of the store (right column) you want to add the terms for. The storeid can be found in the url.

```
insert into catalogsearch_query(query_text, synonym_for, store_id) values('<your_search_term>', '<your_synonym>', <your_store_id>);
```

Comment: I tried that and still when I put in the search term I get taken to the wrong place. Also when I go into the backend to look at the Search terms before I search the term it's not there.

Comment: I can't reproduce the part that you do not see it in the backend. I see the terms in the backend after running the query. Did you try and rerun the catalog search index?

Comment: I just did a test here, and it all worked out. So I'm afraid I need more info to help your any further.
The search term you added via the database query, is that one visible in the admin search term grid or not?
Is so, did you add it to the correct store id?

Comment: No it's not visible in the admin search term grid when I add it using sql. I think this may be one of the problems.

Comment: Which version of Magento are you running?

Comment: I've just tested the query in 1.7.0.2 and it directly is visible in the `Catalog > Search Terms` grid. So I'm afraid you're doing something wrong, but with the information provided I can't really help you any further with this.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I have many tables of magento installed on my server. I was adding it to the wrong one. Your code works perfecty

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. The given answer deals with adding new search terms. In my case I had plenty of search terms and needed to update many of them with the same synonym.
Here is what I did:
Using a query similar to this:

`SELECT query_text,synonym_for 
FROM`catalogsearch_query
`WHERE query_text LIKE '%search_term%'`
to determine the set of search terms that you would like to update as a group.

Then use the following query to update those search terms:

```
`UPDATE catalogsearch_query
SET synonym_for = 'new synonym'
WHERE query_text LIKE '%search_term%'`
```

You will not have all the search terms **for that query** - updated to the new synonym. 
Probably a good idea to back up the table in case you make a mistake.